# MySQL: Insert float, ends up an int

Tags: mysql, types, insert, floating-point, int

I've got a float variable that I'm trying to insert into a float column in my database. The query is as follows:

```
UPDATE users set earnings_unconfirmed = 140834.005336 WHERE username = 'test'
```

I have verified that the column is set to float.

[image]

However when I insert it, it ends up as an int:

[image]

Am I missing something trivial here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A float value only has about seven digits of precision, so the value will be truncated to `140834.0` when you store it, and that is displayed as `140834`.

If you want to store the number with higher precision, use the `double` type instead.

Comment: Or better yet, a `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC` column. Those store exact values, unlike `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.